# Pushing with mercurial: abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I'm not sure why but since today I have the problem with pushing my source to repo. 
I got `abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")`
The thing is that I have `[ui]` section in hgrc:

```
[ui]
username = My username
verbose = true
```

Where's the problem then?

Comment: where is this hgrc file located ?

Comment: You're better off putting that in your home directory in a `.hgrc` or `mercurial.ini` file since your username is usually the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try doing:

```
hg --debug showconfig
```

that shows you all the configuration settings Mercurial is finding and where it's finding them.  Since it looks like you're on windows one possibility is BOMs (byte order markers) at the front of your `hgrc` file.  Nodepad likes to incorrectly put them in there.

In a pinch you can always do `hg --config ui.username=Whatever_you_want commit`, but that's a terrible long term solutions.

Lastly, one expects that error on `commit`, but you said you're getting it on `push`.  I can't imagine how that could happen.

Comment: @AlexanderOrlov are you trying to do it as a command that sets your user name?  That's not what it does.  It let's you override the username on the commit command.

Comment: Just want to add that `[ui]` is case-sensitive, since that was my issue

Answer (score -3):

Either put a hgrc in the .hg directory in your repo or put a hgrc file in your home dir (then it covers all your projects) In the file you should write..

```
[ui]
username = Your Name <your@mail>
```